# Is band theory applicable only for valence electrons

Tags: electronic-band-theory

Is band theory applicable only for the valence energy levels of a metal?

When metal atoms come together the valence electrons occupy a band of energy levels. But does the energy of the inner electrons get affected? Do they continue to have discrete energies?

Comment: Band theory does not apply to atoms. Please edit to clarify your question.